# Returned component in react not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I apologize because I'm sure this has been answered somewhere before but for the life of me I can't find it. I'm trying to make a simple comment box using react and I keep getting the error:

./src/CommentBox.js   Line 29:  'Comment' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

I read online that  needs to be uppercase. I've tried it lower case and my page loads without error but  /  is missing. Sorry if i'm using the wrong terms. I'm new at this.

Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class CommentBox extends React.Component {
render () {
  const comment = this._getComments();
  const commentCount = `{comment.length}`;
  return (

    <div className = "comment-box">
    <h3>COMMENTS</h3>
    <h4 className = "commentCount">
    {this._getCommentsTitle(comment.length)} </h4>
    <div className = "comments">
    {comment}
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

_getComments(){

  const commentList = [
  {id: 1, author: 'Michael Perez', body: 'Awesome Pictures!'},
  {id: 2, author: 'Tofu Kaplan', body: 'Looks like fun but happy you 
  are home :)'}
  ];

  return commentList.map((comment) => {
    return(
        < Comment
        author = {comment.author} body = {comment.body} key = 
        {comment.id} />
    )
  });
}
_getCommentsTitle(commentCount){
  if (commentCount === 1){
  return "1 comment";
  } else {
  return `${commentCount} comments`
  }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to import the `Comment` component at the top of the file

Answer (score 1):

You haven't created any component **Comment**

Comment: Okay so I added this to my _getComments. I don't get the error anymore but my comments still aren't loading. any idea what the issue might be?

function Comment() {
      return(
        <Comment
          author = {comment.author} body = {comment.body} key = {comment.id}/>
    );
  }

Comment: can you add your code to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) and add the link here, it's easier for me to help you this way

Comment: Thanks for the  help, figured it out by warping it in a function() Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You named your React Component `CommentBox`, not `Comment`. Replace `Comment` with proper Component name.

Answer (score 0):

import the Comment component.

```
  import Comment from 'Comment component file name';
```